# Axios doesnt download users from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I wanted to download users from API with axios but I get an error and when I remove {} from UsersProvider it doesn't download anything for me. How could this be fixed or changed?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7db6.png)

File Main:

```
import {UsersProvider} from "../../contexts/Users";

const Main:React.FC= () => {
    const [showUser, setShowUser] = useState("");
    return (
    <div>
        <div>
             <Header/>
        </div>
            <UsersProvider>
                <UsersList/>
                <Debounce onChange={setShowUser}/>
            </UsersProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main
```

File Users:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

type Users = Person[];
type Person = {
    name:string;
    username:string;
}

export const UsersContext = React.createContext<Users>([]);
const UsersProvider:React.FC= ({children}) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<Person[]>([]); 
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then((response) =>{
            setUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },[]);
   
    return (
        <UsersContext.Provider value={users}>
            {children}
        </UsersContext.Provider>
            
    )
}
export default UsersProvider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { UsersProvider } from "../../contexts/Users";
```

Above import is called named import. But, in your code, you have exported `UsersProvider` as the default export in the `../../contexts/Users` file. Hence you're getting that error.

This would work only if you have exported the `UsersProvider` as below in the `../../contexts/Users` file.

```js
export const UsersProvider: React.FC= ({children}) => {
// rest of the code...
```

But, If you don't want to have named exports then you can write your import like this:

```js
import UsersProvider from "../../contexts/Users";
```

Answer (score 0):

`UsersProvider` is a default export .

you need to do

```
import UsersProvider from "../../contexts/Users";
```

Since we are using the context now , we can consume the users in the `UsersList` as

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import UsersContext from 'your path'


const UsersList: React.FC = () => {
    const users = useContext(UsersContext);

    return(
        <div className="ListHead"> 
            <ol className="list">
                {users.map((Person) => (
                    <li key={Person.name}>
                        <span>{Person.name}</span>
                        @{Person.username}
                    </li>
            ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )}
export default UsersList
```

Comment: @konrad edited my answer to fix the other error which you have mentioned ( users list is not getting populated )

Comment: Now it displays everything correctly, but now when I type in the name, nothing changes, before there was only one person left, e.g. Ervin

Comment: can you add the code where you are typing the name ?

Comment: I added this code. Its under us "DebounceInput"

Answer (score 0):

I just did that only I still have no idea why it is not downloading my user list from axios. Everything was working a few months ago, but now it doesn't download at all

Comment: can you show what error you're getting apart from the import error?

Comment: I don't get any error, at the moment when I take {} the whole page loads and you can see everything, but in the place where there was a list before, now there is no

Comment: paste the code of your `usersList` component .

Comment: check this out its working here, https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-kilby-e3cfk

Comment: @Hiren I would also like it to search by name, so that if I enter Ervin, I only get Ervin etc. I have component debounce input but idk why its dont working

Comment: @Konrad, can you create a sandbox like I did and put your code there so we know what exactly are you looking for. Because you're asking the feature by feature questions and moving towards something else which may not be the actual end goal of this question. We'd love to help you and get you up and running, but please be vigialiant as everyone is doing their best to help out people.

Comment: Everything works, jeeez. Thank you so much for your time and help. I am just starting my fun with React and Typescript

Comment: @Konrad Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-firefly-897dp  have fun man!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

type Props = {
    filteredUsers?:Array<Person>;
}
type Person = {
    name:string;
    username:string;
}

const UsersList: React.FC<Props> = ({filteredUsers = []}) =>{

    return(
        <div className="ListHead"> 
            <ol className="list">
                {filteredUsers.map((Person) => (
                    <li key={Person.name}>
                        <span>{Person.name}</span>
                        @{Person.username}
                    </li>
            ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )}
export default UsersList
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this, but maybe something must change here?

```
import React from 'react';
import {DebounceInput} from 'react-debounce-input';
import './style.css';

type Props ={
   onChange:Function;
}

const Debounce:React.FC<Props> = ({onChange}) => {
  return(
        <DebounceInput
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}             
          debounceTimeout={500}                 
          className="SearchInput"                  
          placeholder="Search by user name..."                  
        />      
  )
}

export default Debounce
```

Comment: @Shyam can you help with this?

Comment: @Hiren can you help with this?